# Security: shell scripts to reset the IFS variable against misuse?

Tags: shell, security, environment-variables

From my reading of O'Reilly's "Classic Shell Scripting," it looks like you want to reset the input field separator IFS to newline, space and tab at the start of every shell script to guard against potentially malicious or otherwise malformed input.

Is this actually best practice for every shell script? It doesn't seem practical to include in every shell script, to me.

```
IFS='
     '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, it's definitely not required for best practice, it's just clutter. Historically, it's debatable.

### Historical evolution

Historically, some implementations of sh inherited `IFS` from the environment like any other variable, while others forcibly set it to its default value (space-tab-newline). Most 21st century shells did the latter.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03) used to allow both behaviors:

> Implementations may ignore the value of IFS in the environment at the time the shell is invoked, treating IFS as if it were not set.

“Treating IFS as if it were not set” doesn't actually describe the typical behavior, which is to set it to a value that has the same effect on field splitting as if it was not set. This was discussed in [Austin Group enhancement request 096](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/austin/interps/documents/10027/AI-096.txt) which modified the wording, but still allowed both preserving or overriding `IFS`.

This changed a few years ago, following [Austin Group defect 0000884](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=884) “require sh to set IFS to `<space><tab><newline>` on startup”. This was submitted in 2015 and adopted in the 2016 edition of [POSIX:2008](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) which now states:

> The shell shall set IFS to `<space> <tab> <newline>` when it is invoked.

The rationale is precisely to avoid generally undesirable behavior when scripts don't set `IFS` and run in an environment where it may have been set from an untrusted source.

So nowadays, setting `IFS` explicitly to the default value is only necessary if you work with older shells which are likely to require other deviations from standard practice.

### Was it ever best practice?

If your script inherits environment variables from an untrusted source, there's a lot that can go wrong. `IFS` is just one potential problem amongst many. There's also `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, `PERLLIB`, `PERL5LIB`, `RUBYPATH`, ... Are you confident you set them all? Did you remember `LD_PRELOAD`? `TEXINPUTS`? `RSYNC_RSH`? [Certain variables whose name contains `()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug))?

If your script inherits environment variables with an arbitrary name, *that* is your problem, and you can't fix it from inside the script. Do not run shell scripts where an adversary gets to decide the name of variables in the environment without limitation. That's why [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) only allows whitelisted environment variable names.

Historically, this was mostly a problem in [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) interfaces which didn't filter environment variable names. This was one of the exploitation vectors for [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)). Good modern CGI-like systems add a prefix to all variables and only allow variable names consisting of ASCII alphanumerics-and-underscore.